# Javascript cross-browser: read binary file into an array

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, cross-browser, binaryfiles, readfile

From my Javascript code I would like to read `MyBinaryFile.xxx`, that contains binary data (such as a JPG) and is placed on the server (`String url`). The result of this function should be a byte array.

Is there a way to do this in a cross-browser way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if your file are in the same domain of your script, can be access vial url, then you can use ajax to load that file. Just treat it like normal ajax call.

For example your script in `http://localhost/script.html` want to access a file in `http://localhost/mybin.xxx`. You can do with jQuery

```
$.get('/mybin.xxx', function(data){
    //data will be a byte array with data.length, data[0]....
});
```

Comment: Yes, it is in the same domain of the script. Can you provide a link to a sample code? Thanks

Comment: You can load the data from different domain as well, if that domain allows cross origin resource sharing via `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. Which means that if you control the source domain, you can configure it to load the data from your other domain.

Comment: The answer is INCORRECT. I just tried, and it turns out the bytes over 127, will become 65533.  So this AJAX does NOT support binary at all.  And also, the type of data (`$.type(data)`) is `string`, not a byte array.